# Tons of Cog errors

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

In discord.py 1.0.1 (Only version Repl.it has), the cogs are giving me a hard time.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Coding(commands, Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Kahoot Bot 0.1 ALPHA")
        client.remove_command("help")

    @commands.command()
    async def clear(self, ctx, amount = 5):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount + 1)

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f"Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms.")

    @client.command(pass_context = True, aliases = ["print"])
    async def printing(ctx, *, what_to_print):
        await ctx.send(what_to_print)
        print(what_to_print)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Coding(client))
```

The gist of the errors is:
A) client is not defined
B) **init**() should return None, not coroutine

I've tried changing all my code to bot and back to client, but nothing's helped. No idea what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You do the inheritance wrong. You dont inherit from class: "commands" and "Cog". You inherit from class: "commands.Cog". thus changing: `class Coding(commands, Cog):` to `class Coding(commands.Cog):` will fix some of the errors.

You also do the following wrong (the "client does not exist" error):

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Kahoot Bot 0.1 ALPHA")
        client.remove_command("help") # this line
```

When we want to access a class variable we use `self.` in the beginning of that variable to indicate that we are using the class variable. This case you dont use `self.client.` but `client.`

As client is not defined in that function it will give an error. But it is defined as a class variable (the "init" function). To access it use: `self.client.`